# Speed difference between cat6 and cat5

Tags: ethernet, internet-speed

At what speed am I likely to see a real difference between Cat6 and Cat5 Ethernet cables?

From what I know, there is little difference speed wise when the connection is slow, so what is the minimum speed the connection would need to be to see a real difference (like around 4 or 5 meg)?

Thanks

Comment: There is no reliable way for the electrical devices at each end to know the difference between Cat5 and Cat6, and in many cases devices would be "fat dumb and happy" running with Cat5, even though they theoretically needed Cat6 for the speeds they were running.

Comment: AFAIK Ethernet has no gradual speed degradation. If the cable cannot handle the link bandwidth, the connection drops.

Comment: @DanielRHicks There's not a *reliable* way but if, say, two devices auto-negotiate a gigabit connection, but there are too many e.g. alignment errors, some devices will renegotiate a 100 mbit link. So you can *kind* of tell if a cable can't support the speed if you see too many errors on the wire. That's how you end up with a 100 mbit link sometimes with a bad quality cable, even though both ends can support gigabit.

Comment: @DanielB Ethernet itself doesn't but some protocols on top do. For example, TCP will attempt to retransmit failed / unacknowledged frames, and so you *would* see a gradual speed degradation for TCP connections. But UDP, for example, would manifest as missing packets. Any other protocols that do not perform automatic retransmission would be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speed is the major factor between them but also they help to reduce things like crosstalking (jabbering) as with CAT 6 all the separate wires are independently isolated to stop interference. However I don't know how an expensive CAT 5 cable stands up to a cheap CAT 6 cable, as far as I know there is no actual standard for manufacturing quality on cables.

Comment: Thanks, but i am just looking to find out if the difference in speed is worth the purchase, given my internet connection is only around 10Mbps anyway.  Interference is not an issue for me.

Comment: Nope you won't notice much if any difference if it's only used for WAN (PC to router to outside world) only LAN to LAN really. Although the cost between them isn't much so be surprised if you even find a CAT 5 these days more likely to be CAT 5e which is much closer to CAT 6 not a lot between them.

Comment: @SamDenton Adding to this, in *general* for home use CAT 5e vs UTP 6 vs shielded 6 or 6a don't make much of a difference at all. Generally it makes a significant difference in electrically noisy environments, such as long cable runs, or runs with many cables bundled, or runs that can't be sufficiently distanced from AC lines, etc., none of which really occur in the home. Honestly what I look for in home cabling is quality of the connectors on the ends; given that cable performance differences will be negligible, crappy connectors with poor connections or hard-to-press tabs stink.

Comment: CAT5 though (not CAT5e) you might have trouble with; it was only intended to support up to 100mbps links; it's tricky to get a gigabit link established. CAT5e is not a problem, however.

Comment: @JasonC thanks for the help, that will be useful to know.  I should guess i will go for CAT 5e cables then, as i have found some cheeper than CAT 6 an i only need a short distance.